# Using fscanf() to read from a csv file in C

Tags: c

I'm having a bit of trouble with this piece of code. I have a file products.csv that I'm trying to read values in from and store in a struct. One of the lines are

`Book,B123,The Hunt for Red October,12.99,28`

Because the title has whitespaces in it, I know I need to use `[^,]` instead of `%s` so `fscanf()` doesn't stop at whitespaces, but it's messing up the reading of the file and I don't know exactly how to fix it. Here's the code:

```
typedef struct {
    char productType[15];
    char productID[4];
    char productDescription[100];
    double productPrice;
    int quantityInStock;
} product_t;    

int main() {
    product_t product1;

    read_products(&product1);
}

int read_products(product_t *product) {
    FILE *inFile = fopen("products.csv", "r");

    fscanf(inFile, "%[^,] %[^,] %[^,] %lf %d", product->productType, product->productID, product->productDescription, product->productPrice, product->quantityInStock);

    printf("%s %s %s %lf %d", product->productType, product->productID, product->productDescription, product->productPrice, product->quantityInStock);
}
```

Comment: Another approach is to read your file line by line, and use `strtok()` to parse it.

Comment: Have you tried using `fgets`?

Comment: `fscanf(inFile, "%[^,] %[^,] %[^,] %lf %d", product->productType, product->productID, product->productDescription, &product->productPrice, &product->quantityInStock);`. Note the passing by address for int & floats

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: you need to read the commas too; the first comma in the input blocks the rest of your format string — one field will be read and no more.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  Probably because the `#include <stdio.h> statement is missing\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forcing a space after the comma and you are not parsing the comma. Change this

```
"%[^,] %[^,] %[^,] %lf %d"
```

into this:

```
"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%lf,%d"
```

Other that that you have more errors:

- `productID[4]` you need an array of 5 chars to accomodate for the `\0` terminator.
- `productPrice` and `quantityInStock` are not pointers, so in the `scanf` you need to pass their pointer (`&product->productPrice`, `&product-> quantityInStock`)

Check a working example [here](http://ideone.com/08zlcB).

Comment: After changing it the program stops working. If I do this `"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]%lf%d"` it works to some extent. For some reason the second `[^,]` still takes what should be part of the third one.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that I forgot to accommodate for the endline in productID. That works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically correct — you've diagnosed the fundamental problem and mostly fixed it.  You could use a leading blank to skip initial white space (newlines left over from preceding input, for example). You should probably put a space after the commas and before the `%[^,]`; you should probably put a space before the comma after `%lf`.  Hence, I'd suggest: `" %[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %lf ,%d"`.  (Sneaky question: can you explain why those changes are beneficial?).  Note that line-based input (`fgets()`) and string scanning (`sscanf()`) might be good.  Check the return from `scanf()` family functions.